# Tell me what changed, if anything, in a proposed reopen

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-reopen

In the new review queue, I look at proposed reopens. What I want to know, more often than not, is what, if anything, has the OP or someone else done to improve the question. I *can* answer this question now, but I bet that the UI could make it *easier* to answer this question.

To add an analogy: on a court of appeals, the judges do *not* retry the case. They review the lower court's decision. It is all about reviewing the process, and not about reconsidering the original facts. To me, the review/reopen is a court of appeals for close votes, unless have been edits.

Comment: Why is it important to know if anything has changed in the question? Can't you just evaluate the question itself in its current form?

Comment: I'm trying to decide whether the original closers are right or wrong, or, rather, whether the OP has changed the question. If there are, for example, no changes, then I know I'm just reviewing the judgement of the closers. If there are changes, I'm inclined to focus on them.

Comment: That'll likely make your decision more biased.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - One could make the same argument with 10K escalation flags and invalid flags. Do you think that these bias your decision when looking at flags if you see 2 invalid flags from 10Kers? I always looked at these -- and what Rosinante is proposing -- as a way to help evaluate the question by having more information, and more information should lead to a more informed decision, which could be construed as bias, or it could be construed as ... well ... just having more information to make an informed decision....

Answer (score 10):

Check the history of the question.

If it's been modified you'll see a new revision. This should be able to tell you whether the question has been improved or not.

However, don't forget some closures might just be plain wrong. People can (and do) make mistakes. So a reopen may be called for even though the question hasn't changed at all.